# How to know what all software are there in system in os x using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a way to find out what all softwares are installed / present in OS x, programmatically using objective C. any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system_profiler -xml SPSoftwareDataType

system_profiler -xml SPApplicationsDataType
```

Comment: SPApplicationsDataType works for me, but strange i didn't see this when i did -listDataTypes. Are there more options hidden ??

Comment: I see it in -listDataTypes on both 10.5 and 10.6.  The data types aren't in alphabetical order.

Comment: Yep got it.
Thanks, so if i just execute system_profiler with out any command, its suppose to list entire information including what it shows when we do system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType

Answer (score 0):

[`-findApplications`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/findApplications) method of [`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is what you are looking for. This method is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.6.

You may also want to look at [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).